# Comparing position of two sets of points on 2D image

Tags: algorithm

I've got question about algorithms to compare if two sets of points are in a similar place on the image.

They don't create similar shapes likes `circles`, `rectangles` etc, but they are something like `irregular clouds`.

**For example**:

The first cloud of points is learning set of desired area on image and we are checking if second cloud is in similar position.

I was thinking of drawing simple shapes to form points (like rectangles which will accumulate all points) and checking if one is in another or distance between centers of figures, but this method doesn't seem to be very accurate.

Are there better algorithms to solve this problem?

Comment: Please help us understand your requirements for closeness so we can better understand the situation. For example you could determine how far away a point is from the nearest point and then group points by order of magnitude.

Comment: Can the sets appear in any place of the image? Do you want to know if they are more or less in the same place of the image, or additionally if they have a similar shape as well? Does the scale matter (for example, one set describes a circle or radius X, and the other a circle of radius 3*X)?

Comment: Sets will have quite similar shapes (it will be set of points of human skeleton from kinect sensor) and I want to check if person is sitting in the same place as it was learned in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Image Moments

Don't worry about [the fancy name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment), it's just a standard method in image processing to do exactly what you require.

> Image moment of power n w.r.t. x and m w.r.t. y is actually the
>   integration of (pixel value * xPosition^n * xPosition^m) over the
>   entire image.

So (0, 0)th order moment i.e moment(0, 0) is actually area of the cloud.

Similarly, moment(1, 0)/moment(0, 0) is X coordinate of centroid of the cloud.
And, moment(0, 1)/moment(0, 0) is Y coordinate of centroid of the cloud.

Higher order moments give additional features/information peculiar to shape of the clouds.

---

Now you can easily compare the arbitrary shapes.
These functions are available in opencv and matlab.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: It seems to be helpful. I will try it, but I'm thinking if their is any method to compare sets of points (algebraic) not images, it should be faster method

Comment: It is integrating sets of points.. Just take average of all x and y coordinates. That'd be your centroid (1st order/2nd order moment). That's what I said, it's just fancy names.

Answer (score 0):

> Sets will have quite similar shapes (it will be set of points of human skeleton from kinect > sensor) and I want to check if person is sitting in the same place as it was learned in the > first place

Then you will probably be able to derive a *correspondence* between two points (i.e. you will know that a given point is SHOULDER_RIGHT or ELBOW_LEFT or...). If that is the case you can simply calculate the `SUM(SQRT((Xi1-Xi2)^2+(Yi1-Yi2)^2)` for each i-th pair of points (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2) (same goes if you can obtain the third dimension Z).

The value thus obtained will have a minimum of zero when the two sets of points are perfectly coinciding.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of this method, but in this case I will have to somehow experimental get indicator when distance between two same joints will be grater and this isn't the same place.

Comment: What data do you have at your disposal? You can use center-of-mass estimation to determine whether the place is the same or not.